# How connect SymmetricDS to Kafka?

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, cdc, symmetricds

Can you help me with this one?

I have SymmetricDS, Kafka and HDFS in standalone.

I need to link Symmetric and Kafka together and I have no idea how to do it, I searched on the internet but I didn't catch 'anything'.

If you need any information about my system pls, tell me.

VM Linux Centos 7
I'm installing all in one machine, just testing if this works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Kafka can be used as a target only node in SymmetricDS.  This means that you would capture changes from a variety of relational databases and then setup a Kafka node in SymmetricDS as a load only node to publish the changes onto a Kafka queue.

Here is a link with the steps to setup the Kafka load only node.   There are some advanced options as well that allow you to specify the format of the messages etc.

https://www.jumpmind.com/downloads/symmetricds/doc/3.11/html/user-guide.html#_kafka